# Some emojis dont render properly for flutter textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a textfield widget:

```
TextField(
  controller: _taskNamecontroller,
  focusNode: _focus,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      hintText: SC.current.taskHeaderTaskName),
  style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      height: 1.25),
),
```

and when adding this emoji 1️⃣ from the keyboard, it renders very strangely, it shows the 1 followed by a weird symbol:

[image]

Why is Flutter failing to render this emoji appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

use  GoogleFonts.notoColorEmojiCompat() for style